# SMD-Potentiometer question about Datasheet

Tags: datasheet, surface-mount, potentiometer

I am a bit confused about this Potentiometer-Datasheet.

http://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/PVG3.pdf

Am I right, that the resistance-range is only +-20% of the resistor value? For example, a 5k Potentiometer has only a range from 4k to 6k Ohm?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that it ranges from 0 to 5kOhm +-20% tolerance

Note it doesn't say "Resistance range" but "Total resistance value", meaning when it's at 100%

Comment: Oh, yes. From this point of view you seem to be right :) Thank you

Comment: @FatihY He *is* right. Potentiometers always start at 0 ohm. If you want something that goes from 4k to 6kOhm, it is easy: take a 2kOhm potentiometer and add a 4k resistor in series. If manufacturers had to make any kind of potentiometers ranging from anywhere, up to anywhere, it would be a hell.